# Why TabBar hides after the segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have the next structure:

```
* TabBarController
    - ViewController with TableView
        - ViewController
```

When I select any row on the TableView, the segue forwards me to the ViewController. On the ViewController with the TableView, I see the BottomBar, but after the segue it disappears.

How can I keep it on my ViewController? I've even putted the last ViewController in NavigationController, but it did not help me, too.

How can I fix it?

Comment: This should not happen in normal situations. What kind of segues are you using? Show? Or Present Modally?

Comment: do you have navigation controller right after TabBarController?

Comment: @NickCatib no, but I've tried with it too. Nothing again

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your hierarchy should look like this:

```
* TabBarController
  - NavigationController   
    - ViewController with TableView
      - ViewController
```

Using a `Show` segue with an `UINavigationController` pushes the destination view controller onto the navigation stack. However, most other view controllers present the view modally (i.e. by sliding **over** the source view controller) with `Show`, which is why your tabbar disappears.

Comment: it shows just white space under the viewController, but there are no TabBar =/

Comment: look at this, please: http://imgur.com/aX8LNS1 . You see, there not settings button under the TableView

Comment: So you do have a navigation controller? Can you show the entire setup, including your tabbar controller?

Comment: I've made my structure like you showed above. This is the screen: http://imgur.com/iLEoxWj

Comment: I've just tested that it works with this setup: http://imgur.com/uklPQKl
All the properties were left as default.

Comment: Tab bar should be inferred not translucent

Comment: @NickCatib it shouldn't matter if he has only changed it in the Simulated Metrics.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

uncheck hide bottom bar when pushed from your view controller in story board

Comment: Thanks for this. I was doing some maintenance work and this was the exact reason why the tab bar was not being shown.